# Failed to spawn ngrok in bot framework Emulator in window 11

Tags: window, botframework, ngrok

Ngrok status viewer no any response. Emulator version: 4.14.1
Error as below:

```
Failed to spawn ngrok. Please go to the Ngrok Status Viewer and download the log file for a more detailed view of the error.{"error_code":102,"status_code":400,"msg":"invalid tunnel configuration","details":{"err":"yaml: unmarshal errors:\n line 1: field region not found in type config.HTTPv2Tunnel\n line 1: field path not found in type config.HTTPv2Tunnel"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/2389) caused by breaking changes in Ngrok v3.x. There is already an [open PR](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/pull/2399) to update Emulator to support Ngrok v3.x. Until a new version of Emulator is released, you can work around this issue by using Ngrok v2.x.